# How to create user login script for Windows Vista Home Premium

Tags: windows-vista, login, login-script

I would like to create a script that would allow my daughter to use the computer for a maximum of 3 hours per day during the week.  I've searched the web and can't figure out how to make the User Login execute a script on Windows Vista Home Premium.  I have my computer set up for 4 users.

Step by step instructions would be appreciated, pictures would be excellent.

Is there any documentation on the detailed process Windows Vista uses when logging on?  (Such as which files, commands and their directories that are executed?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use parental control? It's easy, intuitive, is built-in into Windows Vista and works like charm!

See http://www.geekgirls.com/vista_parents.htm and take a look at the section "Restricting time on the computer". You could also check out: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/Control-when-children-can-use-the-computer

It allows for accounts to be limited and controlled from one or several other accounts.

If you're looking for something a bit more advanced and child-friendly, I suggest you take a look at http://www.naturehealth.eu/children-care-index.html. Works pretty well.

Comment: Parental Controls only allows for time slots to be blocked or unblocked, it does not allow for duration.  For example, I want to restrict the time to 3 hours duration between 3:00 p.m. until 9:00 p.m.  With Parental Control, I would have to unblock 6 hours, even though I only want her to have 3 hours, but any three during the duration.

Comment: @thomas Check out the last link of my answer then.

Comment: I can write my own software, I just want to know the login process for Windows Vista.  The *nix family has this knowledge published (I've been System Administrator on Unix and Linux systems).  Another reason I don't get along with Microsoft. :-(

Comment: And you want to write your own software just because you can? Why re-invent the wheel? Anyway, uou can use Group Policy to set a startup script that runs at login.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure about the script but to make it automatically start you can use the 'startup' folder. It can be found on your programs menu. Anything in that folder will be executed on startup (i.e. scripts, shortcuts, or otherwise) also if you haven't already you might read [this](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vistasecurity/thread/98543dfa-783b-4ae8-b464-c274bce895ec) if you don't mind using free third party software then check [this](http://thethinkingmother.blogspot.com/2007/06/free-software-helps-limit-kids-computer.html) out

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Many people may not want to purchase the 3rd party apps.  Since I am a software engineer, I thought I could come up with my own application, provided I knew the Windows login sequence.  Unix (and brethren) is sooo much easier in this arena.